# Gather the values of certain columns into one column

Tags: r

I want to convert the values of the second and third columns of the dataframe below to one column with 6 rows.

```
fi<-c("a","b","c")
se<-c("d","e","f")
th<-c("g","h","1")
daf<-data.frame(fi,se,th)
```

Im trying something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(fi)){
  First <- data.frame(t(daf[i,-1]))
}
```

Comment: Do you need `tidyr::gather(daf, key, value, -1)` ?

Comment: yes that would do the job

Comment: Great. Actually, this has been asked before and I have marked it as duplicate. Hope that is fine and it also shows different ways to solve the same problem.

Comment: I get :attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped  as warning message

Comment: And as a result many empty cells

Comment: That warning message can be removed if you create your dataframe by doing `daf<-data.frame(fi,se,th, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. Also I don't see any empty cells in example you shared.